# How do I create an object from data in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state

How do you create an object model in React state (for a Function Component), given the code below?

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>Input 1</label>
    <input id="1" />
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label>Input 2</label>
    <input id="2" />
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label>Input 3</label>
    <input id="3" />
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <label>Input 4</label>
    <input id="4" />
</div>
```

```
const dataToPost = [
        ...document.querySelectorAll("div.form-row"),
    ].map((f) => {
        let obj = {};
        f.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(
            (item) => (
                (obj["id"] = item.id), (obj["value"] = item.value || "")
            )
        );
        return obj;
    });
```

This outputs the result I want...

```
"dataToPost": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "value": "input one value"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "value": "input two value"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "value": "input three value"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "value": "input four value"
    }
]
```

Then is it possible to use an on change event for each input to update it's state object, given it needs to be a Function component?

Comment: rather than div you can create object on input id .

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? Normally the data flow goes the other way round: you get some JSON structure from the backend, and, based on that you render the frontend. I have never seen a valid use case (in my 12 years of IT development experience) to parse an HTML structure and make a JSON out of it... But please let me know if I'm wrong...

Comment: Hi, you are right there! The JSON goes through a simple Input component which gives each form row in the HTML. But not sure how to use state in a scenario like above, as the JSON is dynamic and inputs can vary, so not sure how to in React useState in the right way to listen to changes of all inputs rendered and that update onChange properly

Comment: is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-forest-i7ur3?file=/src/App.js) what you want to do?

Comment: @Yousaf yes that is what I am trying to do! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom hook to keep the state of the form in the format you want and also update the form state on `onChange` event

Follow the following step:

1. convert

   ```
   <div class="form-row">
       <label>Input 1</label>
       <input id="1" />
   </div>
   ```

   in to a component that will represent a single input element and its label.
2. Create a custom hook that will keep the state of the form

   ```
   import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

   function useForm() {
     const [data, setData] = useState([
       { id: 1, value: "" },
       { id: 2, value: "" },
       { id: 3, value: "" },
       { id: 4, value: "" }
     ]);

     const updateForm = useCallback(
       ({ target }) => {
           const arr = [...data];
           const obj = arr.find(o => o.id === Number(target.name));

           obj.value = target.value;
           setData(arr);
       },
       []
     );

     return [data, updateForm];
   }

   export default useForm;
   ```
3. Create a `Form` component that will render all the `Input` components. This `Form` component will use the `useForm` hook that was created in step 2. In this component, we will loop over the form state and render the individual `Input` components and pass the appropriate props to `Input` elements and also pass the `onChange` event handler that will update the form state whenever any input changes.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import useForm from "./useForm";
   import Input from './Input';

   function Form() {
      const [data, setData] = useForm();

      return (
       <>
         {
           data.map((input, idx) => (
              <Input
                 key={idx}
                 type="text"
                 value={input.value}
                 label={`Input ${++idx}`}
                 name={input.id}
                 setValue={setData}
              />
           ))
          }
       </>
     );
   }

   export default Form;
   ```

Here's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-forest-i7ur3?file=/src/App.js) of above mentioned steps.

P.S. `useCallback` hook and `React.memo` have been used for optimization. This prevents unnecessary re-rendering of all `Input` components whenever an `onChange` event is fired on any of the `Input` component